# iTextSharp show Bookmarks but not in my document

Tags: itext

I have an application that is creating a document with the iTextSharp library, the document consists of a custom TOC which is created with a List which contain ListItems that contain Chunks that have PdfAction.GotoLocalPage action, these pages that re linked are PDF's that are merged to one document. I'm able to add a Chapter object to these between leaves and the bookmark is created. But after the merge I don't have the bookmarks in my final document. I also want to hide the text and number in the document not in Acrobat Reader. I have a custom layout for these between leaves and don't want the created text from the chapter. I can hide the number already with.

http://tiku.io/questions/671594/hide-number-of-sections-and-chapters-in-itextsharp

Thx in advance !!

Comment: Can you rephrase the question? Right now, it is very hard to understand whether you're asking a question that has been answered many times before ("How can I merge documents and preserve the original bookmarks") or if you're talking about a complex and exotic requirement (if so, break up your question in simple parts so that simple minds like mine can understand the question).

Comment: OK, my question is answered by myself. I didn't fully understand what PDF Bookmarks actually were I though the bookmarks also created a sort of table of contents in my document, but it created it on document level not content level. I manually created a table of content with named destinations.